# Synfony 2.8 - Cannot register enum type

Tags: php, symfony, enums

I am new to php development and trying to create my first application using symfony.

I created my model description using the YAML files, but I can't get rid of this error when trying to update the DB :

> [Doctrine\DBALDBALException]   Unknown column type "enum" requested.

I tried to add the following configuration in config.yml:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    mapping_types:
        enum: string
```

I also tried to add the following instructions in my bundle class:

```
    public function boot()
{
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    $platform = $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
    $platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
}
```

None of them worked. I still got the same error...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the symfony2 framework or are you using component? Secondly, is your config.yml's structure like that exactly or has it formatted incorrectly? As your dbal is inline with your doctrine.

Comment: Hi, i'm using the symfony2 framework. Also, my original config.yml has correct indentation (smth went wrong when I copy pasted it here)

Comment: What version of SF framework are you using?

Comment: Thx Liam! Thanks to your question I was able to notice I used SF 3.1.4 whereas I thought I used SF 2.8 !
I know have other issues, when generating the entities. But once it's fixed I will keep you in touch. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think I messed up with my entity definition...
I used 'enum' as the entity type and that's probably the reason why it didn't work since it's not a default type in doctrine dbal. Can't remember why I did this.
I used this instead: https://github.com/fre5h/DoctrineEnumBundle

Answer (score 0):

You could add custom DBAL doctrine types if needed. But you would have to create one Type class for each different SET() or ENUM() type.

Here is how I done my custom SET() types. You could done something similar for ENUM. Given code could be improved further but for now it suffice.

*app/config/config.yml*

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            period_set:  Acme\AcmeBundle\DBAL\PeriodSetType
```

*src/Acme/AcmeBundle/DBAL/PeriodSetType.php*

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\DBAL;

use Acme\AcmeBundle\DBAL\MySQLSetType;


class PeriodSetType extends MySQLSetType {

    protected $name = 'period_set';
    protected $values = ['second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day', 'weekday', 'month', 'year'];
}
```

*src/Acme/AcmeBundle/DBAL/MySQLSetType.php*

```
namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\DBAL;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;


class MySQLSetType extends Type {

    protected $name = 'my_sql_set';
    protected $values = [];

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return sprintf("SET('%s')", implode("','", $this->values));
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value === null || $value === '') {
            return [];
        }
        if (strpos($value, ',') === false) {
            return [$value];
        }
        return explode(',', $value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        //SF 2.7+ choice field was changed, so it returns string only, set requires array 
        if (is_string($value) and $value != '') {
            $value = (array) $value;
        }
        if (!is_array($value) || count($value) <= 0) {
            return null;
        }
        $diff = array_diff($value, $this->getValues());
        if (count($diff) > 0) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                    'Invalid value "%s". It is not defined in "%s::$choices"',
                    implode(',', $diff),
                    get_class($this)
                )
            );
        }
        return implode(',', $value);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getValues()
    {
        return $this->values;
    }
}
```

Entity field @annotation is as following:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="period_set", nullable=true)
 */
private $timeResponseUnit = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes indeed, this is how I finally did it, using https://github.com/fre5h/DoctrineEnumBundle. It looks like I didn't need this bundle, though